# avahi-daemon fails to start at start-up

Tags: boot, noobs

My RPI is running on NOOBS. `avahi-daemon` fails to start at start-up

I need to do

```
sudo service dbus start
sudo service avahi-daemon start
```

to start it. How can I start `dbus` before `avahi-daemon` at start-up or is there any issue that preventing `dbus` to start at startup?

Comment: Yos can't be running NOOBS because it isn't an OS - only a loader. If you are running Raspbian you should use `systemctl` but you don't need to run these manually.

Comment: `systemctl` command not found